# Kafka Connect FileStreamSink connector does not include the KEY in the output file

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Trying a simple File sink connector to extract data from a topic. The generated file does not include the event key and I am not able to find a setting that enables that. Eventually the goal will be to load the file using a source connector and produce the same sample data and the event KEY is very important.

Thanks

```
{
    "name": "save-seed-data",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "name": "save-seed-data", 
        "topics": "FIRM",
        "file": "/tmp/FIRM.txt",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where you found that the key should be in the output, since [the source code only references the value](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSinkTask.java#L80).

You can download and use a message transform to move the key over into the value, though.

https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive

---

Also worth mentioning, that the FileStream Source Connector does not parse the data. Each line, also, [only goes into the value](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.6/connect/file/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/file/FileStreamSourceTask.java#L154)

---

Generally, using `kafkacat` is much more straightforward for dumping/loading data from files.